# Is there a bug in my CV print?

Tags: bug, developer-story

Here is my [CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/xameeramir). About a year ago, when printed it used to include my photo as well.

Now, it doesn't do it. I tested it on different browsers.

- Is there a bug
- Is there a change?

Comment: @DeanWard Is it a low priority thing for you?